# Show sub-options based on selected main option in Codeigniter by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

I would like when I select the *cats* option that only the breed of cats appears, such as the Siamese example. If I select *dog*, I only want to get the breed of dogs, such as Pitbull and others.

Can you help me with the code, it tells me to use jquery, but how is it done I am just learning?

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="especie">Especie</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="id_especie" name="id_especie" value="data-id-especie=">
                <option value="">Seleccionar especie</option>
                <?php foreach ($especie as $row) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="raza">Raza</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="id_raza" name="id_raza">
                <option value="">Seleccionar raza</option>
                <?php foreach ($raza as $row) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of first dropdown]

[image: Screenshot of second dropdown]

Comment: what you want `dynamic dependant drop down list`??

Comment: yes my friends.

Comment: so then try with my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Question you want **Dynamic dependant drop down list** in codeigniter with ajax / jQuery.

**PHP VIEW :**

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="especie">Especie</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="id_especie" name="id_especie" value="data-id-especie=">
            <option value="">Seleccionar especie</option>
            <?php foreach ($especie as $row) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="raza">Raza</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="id_raza" name="id_raza">
         <!-- Data here will be auto populated by ajax -->

            </select>
    </div>
```

**Controller :**

```
public function get_data()
           {
                $id_especie = $this->input->post("id_especie");
     $SUbCatdata = $this->db->get_where('tableName',array('id'=>$id_especie))->result_array();
            $option ="<option selected disabled value=''>Select Name</option>";
              foreach($SUbCatdata as $row)
              {
                 $option.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
              }
               echo $option;
           }
```

**jQuery / Ajax :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_especie").on("change",function(){
        var id_especie = $(this).val();
     
        $.ajax({
             url : "<?php echo base_url('Controller/get_data') ?>",
             type: "post",
             data: {"id_especie":id_especie},
             success : function(data){
                //alert(data);
        $("#id_raza").html(data);
             }
        });
    });
    
    </script>
```

**Note :** For more info regarding **change()**

https://api.jquery.com/change

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a sub-dropdown list that is dependent on the selection of another (main) dropdown list. If this is the case, here's what you need to do.

First, you need to create a file that contains code that will fetch results based on what is supplied. That is (in your example), if the main category is *"dogs"*, it will query the database for all *"species"* of dogs, and return the result. Something like this:

**Category Controller**

```
class Category_controller extends CI_Controller{
    // Get Subcategory method
    public function get_subcategory()
    {
        // Check if input ($_GET or $_POST) exists
        if ( $this->input->post_get() )
        {
            $main_cat_id = $this->input->post_get('mainid'); // main category id
            
            // Perform your db query here to get the subcategory of the main cat
            // Echo the result after performing a foreach loop like you did in the 
            // html file. <option value="value_id">value name</option>
            $result = ""; // store empty value first
            foreach ($dbresult as $value)
            {
                $result .= '<option value="$value['id']">$value['nombre']</option>';
            }
            echo $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**SubCategory.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="id_especie"]').on('change', function() {
        var catid = $(this).val(); // will get the value attribute of the selected main category

        // Perform ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url-to-the-subcategory-controller', // remember to set this in your config/routes.php file
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {mainid: catid},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('select#id_raza').html(data); // update the subcategory dropdown
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

So, your second select box `select#id_raza` show look like so in your view file:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="raza">Raza</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="id_raza" name="id_raza">
            <option value="">Seleccionar raza</option>
            <!-- Data here will be auto populated by ajax -->
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)